# What does it truly mean to love and hate for the sake of Allah?

Tags: practical-islam

What does it truly mean to love and hate for the sake of Allah?

Please give a good answer, taking into context today's reality and how one must act to achieve this! I'm talking about al-wala and bara.

Comment: Al-wal and bara? What are they?

Comment: It means to be loyal and disassociate for the sake of Allah. i.e love and hate what Allah loves and hates or for his sake alone.

Comment: Noticed you were new to Stack Exchange, so just wanted to clarify. Did you know that you can accept answers on your question. Just press the check mark to the left of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The prophet saaws once said:“None of you is a believer until he loves for his brother (his fellow Muslims) what he loves for himself.” (Sahih Muslim)

Islam truley emphasizes the lesson of love to those who love allah.

the prophet also said

> "No, by Him in Whose Hand my soul is, (you will not have complete faith) till I am dearer to you than your own self." Then 'Umar said to him, "However, now, by Allah, you are dearer to me than my own self." The Prophet said, "Now, O 'Umar, (now you are a believer)." bukhari 78:628

the reason for this is if you love the prophet and those who are good you will want to be like these people. Also by loving those who love allah, its demonstrating your own love for allah.

If you think about it todays example, you will see that many people idolize celebraties musicians, and others who do no benifit to the world. This wouldnt be loving people for the sake of allah, it would in fact be the opposite if you love somone who denies that allah exists. Also, when you love people of negative influence, you will want to act like these people.However, if you love people like the prophet, you local mosque sheikh, a very righteous person, you will have influence to be like these people.Also, you would be loving these peopel for allah, you are giving these wondrful people you love to them and allah, and benifiting yourself with their example. This is what it mean to love people for allah.

so in conclusion by loving those who love allah you demonstrate your love for allah, and you recive your influence from them to become a better muslim.

Comment: can someone shed some light on having association and disassociation in today's reality i.e. with all this non-islamic stuff going on and many muslims have love for this etc.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your perspective of your faith.

> But as for those who believed and did righteous deeds, He will give them in full their rewards, and Allah does not like the wrongdoers. [3:57]
>
> أَمَّا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ فَيُوَفِّيهِمْ أُجُورَهُمْ ۗ وَاللَّـهُ لَا يُحِبُّ الظَّالِمِينَ

Take this verse from Surat Al-i-Imran for example. Allah states that he rewards those who do righteous deeds, but does not like the disbelievers. Does this mean that you should dislike the disbelievers? No.

> For you is your religion, and for me is my religion." [109:6]
>
> لَكُمْ دِينُكُمْ وَلِيَ دِينِ

So really, Allah does not tell you in the Quran to hate what He hates, and love what He loves. He tells you to do what was told of you, and that He dislikes and punishes those who don't.

Comment: Thanks for that, your bit about Allah doesn't tell you to hate what he hates etc in the Quran. There is a discussion amongst the scholars about this, so something like loving a football star isn't something Islam glorifies on the contrary to love your mother and family this Allah and his messenger love for you to do.

Comment: @abushahin That just proves my point. Allah doesn't tell you who or who not to love/hate, besides things like your parents and family. He tells you what _he_ loves and hates.

Answer (score 1):

to not care about what people and even yourself want and only care about what God wants. so you should first know all laws of Islam which are wants of God.

Quran says respect your parents but:

> And We have enjoined upon man goodness to parents. But if they
>   endeavor to make you associate with Me that of which you have no
>   knowledge, do not obey them. To Me is your return, and I will inform
>   you about what you used to do. (8)

http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/29:8

this means for sake of Allah you even should not obey your parents if they say something opposite of what Allah says.

also recite this Ziarat every day.
this is the best Love and Hate for sake of Allah:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashura

Imam Ali S.A. for sake of Allah killed so much Arabs from his own relatives in wars of prophet with pagan Arabs like Abu sufyan that he was called by Arabs "the killer of Arab" قتال العرب  and so many of them hated him.

or prophet Ibrahim for sake of God wanted to slaughter his son.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as loving what Allah loves, hating what Allah hates without the interference of your choice/desire/like/preference. Of course it is not so simple when you want to apply this principle to your life. Trying to live a life like this is true/greater jihad and brings in sincerity.

Answer (score 0):

You love Allah by obeying His commands (laws) and loving as well as emulating Rasullulah(SAW),the pious and hating that which is evil.